# In OctoberCMS Multiple File Upload In Admin Section

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am trying to upload multiple files in my custom component. First I have tried with  **mediafinder** then **fileupload** but seems like nothing working.

I have google for admin section file upload.but there is no demo/example of multiple file upload in which user can upload multiple images and **which is store uploaded file name in separate table**.

Can anyone give me any demo/sample link of multiple file upload in admin section?

Answer (score 1):

To attach file to a model you need to use **System\Models\File** in a **attachOne** or **attachMany** relation

```
public $attachOne = [
    'myfile' => 'System\Models\File'
];

public $attachMany = [
    'myfiles' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

documentation : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments

Add this myFile or myFiles into you backend form by editing the fields.yaml file.

```
myFile :
    label: myFile
    type: fileupload
    mode: file
```

fileupload - renders a file uploader for images or regular files. The field name must use an attachOne or attachMany relation.

The result would be

[image]